# Does AEM 6.0 supports integrated windows authorization

Tags: aem

Does AEM 6.0 supports integrated windows authorization using aem SAML or LDAP handlers

Answer (score 1):

Sure, follow the LDAP instructions on [this page](http://docs.adobe.com/docs/de/aem/6-0/administer/security/ldap-config.html) and for the saml docs click [here](https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-0/administer/security/saml-2-0-authenticationhandler.html). You may also want to check the saml integration demo [on this page](https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/kb/saml-demo.html). If none of these fits your need, you have still the possibility to write your own authentification handlers.